# Retrieving the value of RETURN @@IDENTITY in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Here's a very simple question. I have an SP that inserts a row into a table and at the end there's the statement RETURN @@IDENTITY. What I can't seem to find is a way to retrieve this value in C#. I'm using the Enterprise library and using the method:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

I've tried **cmd.Parameters[0].Value** to get the value but that returns 0 all the time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim c as new sqlcommand("...")

Dim d As New SqlParameter()
d.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
c.parameters.add(d)

c.executeNonQuery

(@@IDENTITY) = d.value
```

It is more or less like this...either this or just return the value from a stored procedure as an output parameter.

Comment: You need to add the parameter to the command, but almost there.

Comment: Thats what this line does - c.parameters.add(d) ... though I might have put that in whilst editing whilst you were writing this comment.

Comment: Yea, that was the case. Not sure if the parameter name needs to be defined so I posted my own response as well.

Answer (score 5):

BTW, in most circumstances, you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() rather than @@IDENTITY. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185.aspx).

Comment: I agree, but in this context it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: There isn't enough information given to determine that. You should only ever use @@IDENTITY when you actually require it.

Answer (score 2):

One point to mention. You should really use SCOPE_IDENTITY to return the identity value after INSERT. There is potential for @@IDENTITY to return the wrong value. Especially if TRIGGERS are in use, writing value to other tables after INSERT.

See the [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) page for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Someone says use

IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303448-return-identity-after-sql-insert.html

-Zubair
http://zubairdotnet.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to execute with a scalar value

```
SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

as others have mentioned I think using SCOPE_IDENTITY() is more secure than the @@IDENTITY variable

Comment: the SP would need to end : select @@IDENTITY rather than return for this to work.