# How to return @@Identity or Scope_Identity into C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the value of RETURN @@IDENTITY in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246321/retrieving-the-value-of-return-identity-in-c)

I have a class with different methods and constructors. In SaveDB() I select @@IDENTITY but I'm not sure how to return it into C#. I see there are some other posts about this on Stack, but I don't see any direct answers for C#. Any help is appreciated.

The result I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
     int mySiteUserID;

    mySiteUserID = 4; //4 is the Identity of the last saved SiteUser
```

```
    public class SiteUser
    {


    #region Fields
    private int siteUserID;
    private string siteUserFirstName;
    private string siteUserLastName;
    private string siteUserTitle;
    private string siteUserEmail;
    private string siteUserPhone;
    private string siteUserPassword;
    private int siteUserType;
    private int companyID;
    private bool siteUserActive;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int SiteUserID { get { return siteUserID; } set { siteUserID = value; } }
    public string SiteUserFirstName { get { return siteUserFirstName; } set { siteUserFirstName = value; } }
    public string SiteUserLastName { get { return siteUserLastName; } set { siteUserLastName = value; } }
    public string SiteUserTitle { get { return siteUserTitle; } set { siteUserTitle = value; } }
    public string SiteUserEmail { get { return siteUserEmail; } set { siteUserEmail = value; } }
    public string SiteUserPhone { get { return siteUserPhone; } set { siteUserPhone = value; } }
    public string SiteUserPassword { get { return siteUserPassword; } set { siteUserPassword = value; } }
    public int SiteUserType { get { return siteUserType; } set { siteUserType = value; } }
    public int CompanyID { get { return companyID; } set { companyID = value; } }
    public bool SiteUserActive { get { return siteUserActive; } set { siteUserActive = value; } }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public SiteUser()
    {
        siteUserID = 0;
        siteUserFirstName = "";
        siteUserLastName = "";
        siteUserTitle = "";
        siteUserEmail = "";
        siteUserPhone = "";
        siteUserPassword = "";
        siteUserType = 0;
        companyID = 0;
        siteUserActive = false;
    }
    public SiteUser(int PrimaryKeyValue)
    {
        string sql = @"
        SELECT *
        FROM SiteUsers
        WHERE SiteUserID = @PrimaryKeyValue";
        SqlParameter[] parms = new SqlParameter[1];
        parms[0] = new SqlParameter("@PrimaryKeyValue", PrimaryKeyValue);

        SqlDataReader dr = DBUtil.FillDataReader(sql, parms);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            this.siteUserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["siteUserID"].ToString());
            this.siteUserFirstName = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserFirstName"].ToString());
            this.siteUserLastName = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserLastName"].ToString());
            this.siteUserTitle = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserTitle"].ToString());
            this.siteUserEmail = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserEmail"].ToString());
            this.siteUserPhone = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserPhone"].ToString());
            this.siteUserPassword = Convert.ToString(dr["siteUserPassword"].ToString());
            this.siteUserType = Convert.ToInt32(dr["siteUserType"].ToString());
            this.companyID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["companyID"].ToString());
            this.siteUserActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["siteUserActive"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
    }

    #endregion


    public int SaveDB()
    {
        //db code to write record
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString);

        string sql = "";


        if (SiteUserID == 0)
        {
            //this is an insert
            sql = @"
                INSERT SiteUsers(
    --SiteUserID,
    SiteUserFirstName,
    SiteUserLastName,
    SiteUserTitle,
    SiteUserEmail,
    SiteUserPhone,
    SiteUserPassword,
    SiteUserType,
    CompanyID,
    SiteUserActive

                 )VALUES(
    --@SiteUserID,
    @SiteUserFirstName,
    @SiteUserLastName,
    @SiteUserTitle,
    @SiteUserEmail,
    @SiteUserPhone,
    @SiteUserPassword,
    @SiteUserType,
    @CompanyID,
    @SiteUserActive

                );
    SELECT @@IDENTITY
    ";

        }
        else
        {
            //this is an update //siteUserID = @siteUserID
            //this is an update //siteUserFirstName = @siteUserFirstName
            //this is an update //siteUserLastName = @siteUserLastName
            //this is an update //siteUserTitle = @siteUserTitle
            //this is an update //siteUserEmail = @siteUserEmail
            //this is an update //siteUserPhone = @siteUserPhone
            //this is an update //siteUserPassword = @siteUserPassword
            //this is an update //siteUserType = @siteUserType
            //this is an update //companyID = @companyID
            //this is an update //siteUserActive = @siteUserActive
            sql = @"
            UPDATE SiteUsers
                SET 
    --SiteUserID = @SiteUserID,
    SiteUserFirstName = @SiteUserFirstName,
    SiteUserLastName = @SiteUserLastName,
    SiteUserTitle = @SiteUserTitle,
    SiteUserEmail = @SiteUserEmail,
    SiteUserPhone = @SiteUserPhone,
    SiteUserPassword = @SiteUserPassword,
    SiteUserType = @SiteUserType,
    CompanyID = @CompanyID,
    SiteUserActive = @SiteUserActive

                WHERE SiteUserID = 
    @SiteUserID
                                        ";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        SqlParameter siteUserIDParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserID", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter siteUserFirstNameParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserLastNameParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserTitleParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserEmailParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserPhoneParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserPasswordParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter siteUserTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserType", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter companyIDParam = new SqlParameter("@companyID", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter siteUserActiveParam = new SqlParameter("@siteUserActive", SqlDbType.Bit);

        siteUserIDParam.Value = siteUserID;
        siteUserFirstNameParam.Value = siteUserFirstName;
        siteUserLastNameParam.Value = siteUserLastName;
        siteUserTitleParam.Value = siteUserTitle;
        siteUserEmailParam.Value = siteUserEmail;
        siteUserPhoneParam.Value = siteUserPhone;
        siteUserPasswordParam.Value = siteUserPassword;
        siteUserTypeParam.Value = siteUserType;
        companyIDParam.Value = companyID;
        siteUserActiveParam.Value = siteUserActive;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserIDParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserFirstNameParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserLastNameParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserTitleParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserEmailParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserPhoneParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserPasswordParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserTypeParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(companyIDParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(siteUserActiveParam);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return 0;
    }

    }
```

Comment: My eyes, they hurt.  Have you considered using an ORM like Linq to SQL, and hooking it up with an `ObjectDataSource`?

Comment: Or at least start using [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/2009/12/09/Getting-the-identity-of-a-row-inserted-into-a-database-table-with-SCOPE_IDENTITY.aspx

Comment: From what I've heard, Linq is slow and not really used in real world production.

Comment: @Barrett: Linq != Linq to SQL. Use EF if you like. Linq to SQL is used here on Stack Overflow, although they do use some custom code when they want to go *really* fast. Sam Saffron [wrote some custom ORM code](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) for Stack Overflow, but I suppose once you get this big, that's a *good* problem. Linq to SQL works just fine under the vast majority of *ordinary* scenarios.

Comment: @Barrett - that is false. Linq to Sql is used in production in many places. StackOverflow started out with L2S (not sure if they're still running it), but they were doing millions of transactions per day with L2S, and it's one of the snappyest websites I use (wicked performance).

Comment: @RobertHarvey from what I've heard, there are more performance complaints associated with EF than there is with L2S, but that could just be hearsay.

Comment: Linq to SQL is [more than adequate for the StackOverflow site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/is-stackoverflow-still-using-linq-to-sql-as-the-orm) which is more "real world" than most enterprise web apps ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute your script, use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, and convert the result to an `int`. The script will still have the side-effect that a row gets inserted, but it's value will be the scope identity.

Comment: That should work, provided `;select scope_identity()` is added to the end of the SQL statement.